# How to Add HeatMaps to Flutter Mobile app

Tags: google-maps, mobile, flutter, dart, heatmap

I'm trying to add a Heatmap to GoogleMaps in flutter, I can't find any reference to this in the documentation, is there a way to do so.? I know there is a way to do so on Web. 
Is there an alternative to this.? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google map library for Flutter is not fully complete yet, many of the functions of google map are not available in Flutter at this moment but I think in the next versions those functions should be include

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks

Comment: Is there a suggested work around right now or is it a case of writing something custom?

Comment: Please share any real code example if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pub package [google_maps_flutter_heatmap](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_heatmap) forked from the original `google_maps_flutter` as a quick workaround. I think the flutter team is still working on it. But in the meantime use this, it worked for me on android (iOS support is not tested yet).

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_heatmap/google_maps_flutter_heatmap.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Heatmap Demo',
      home: MapSample(),
    );
  }
}

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  final Set<Heatmap> _heatmaps = {};
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
  LatLng _heatmapLocation = LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962);
  static final CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        heatmaps: _heatmaps,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _addHeatmap,
        label: Text('Add Heatmap'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _addHeatmap(){
    setState(() {
      _heatmaps.add(
        Heatmap(
          heatmapId: HeatmapId(_heatmapLocation.toString()),
          points: _createPoints(_heatmapLocation),
          radius: 20,
          visible: true,
          gradient:  HeatmapGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Colors.green, Colors.red], startPoints: <double>[0.2, 0.8]
          )
        )
      );
    });
  }
  //heatmap generation helper functions
  List<WeightedLatLng> _createPoints(LatLng location) {
    final List<WeightedLatLng> points = <WeightedLatLng>[];
    //Can create multiple points here
    points.add(_createWeightedLatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude, 1));
    points.add(_createWeightedLatLng(location.latitude-1,location.longitude, 1)); 
    return points;
  }

  WeightedLatLng _createWeightedLatLng(double lat, double lng, int weight) {
    return WeightedLatLng(point: LatLng(lat, lng), intensity: weight);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the official package hasn't implemented heatmaps yet ([well, there's a PR, but it seems abandoned](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2454)), here's what I found about the feature:

1. [Here is a fork that implements heatmap feature both on Android and iOS](https://github.com/SvenSlijkoord/plugins/tree/implement_google_maps_flutter_heatmap), but have some display issues on iOS (heatmap correctly displays on both OS, but locations on iOS have an incorrect opacity, as shown below);

[image: heatmap correctly displays on Android]
[image: locations displays, but with incorrect opacity on iOS]

2. Somebody [forked](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_heatmap) the fork above on April, but [cannot test it on iOS](https://github.com/bmabir17/google_maps_flutter_heatmap/issues/1).
3. Instead of Google Map heatmaps, I looked for [Mapbox](https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl) heatmaps, unfortunately it's also [not implemented](https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/issues/360).

Maybe there's a way [using Leaflet maps](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/264).

Comment: did u find a way?!

Comment: Using the above-mentioned fork, I managed to display heatmaps on both Android and iOS by tweaking settings a bit.


Screenshots: https://github.com/pandemia-app/pandemia/pull/31
Code snippet: https://github.com/pandemia-app/pandemia/pull/31/commits/c646f6fee87fc7acf04cbe05cb3ccfb284f9ab30


However, keep in mind that this code is more than one year old, and that alternatives may have arise since then.